# Check if an item is already in the ember-data store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am making a lot of async calls and using loadMany to preload the ember data store like this:

```
if(data.feed.activities.length > 0){
  App.store.loadMany(App.Activity, data.feed.activities);
}
```

Some of my bindings are screwing up if I am readding the same item more than once which is a possibility.

Is there a way of not reloading the item if it is already in the store?  I don't want to have to iterate over each item and check if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the load() documentation in store.js

> "Load a new data hash into the store for a given id and type
>   combination. If data for that record had been loaded previously, the
>   new information overwrites the old. If the record you are loading data
>   for has outstanding changes that have not yet been saved, an exception
>   will be thrown."

As you can see, the new information overwrites the old, so it should be ok to reload the same data. Maybe you have another issue. Have you configured your id correctly?